# Run Android APK files in web browser - Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, web, apk

I am looking to write a web page that can load to it and run APK files. Something like a web control that can get an APK file url, load it and let the user interact with the app (No need in the whole android system, just the specified APK).

Is it possible? Is there anything like that in the market? Maybe a standalone open source emulator i can migrate to work on the web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no, but not fully impossible

Long answer: [BlueStacks](http://bluestacks.com/) provides a raw and unstable emulation framework that is able to run single APKs without the full Android device emulation, but while it's not designed to run in a webpage, it actually executes as an ActiveX.